# How to disable Browser Sync?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I'm working on a big AngularJS app. It features this Browser Sync, but it gets really hard to debug when your network looks like this:

[image: network]

How can I disable Browser Sync? I cannot seem to find any config around. I tried changing the Browsersync modules folders, but GULP just throws an error.

Comment: DId you look at your gulp tasks? Is there a gulpfile.js?